# stopping the keydown event in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

How can i stop keydown event in my current situation?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Focus();
    textBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MyKeyPress);
}

public void MyKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    string first = e.Modifiers.ToString();

    if (first != "None")
    {
        if ((e.KeyCode != Keys.ShiftKey) && (e.KeyCode != Keys.Alt) && (e.KeyCode != Keys.ControlKey))
        {
            textBox1.Text = e.Modifiers.ToString() + " & " + e.KeyCode.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = e.KeyCode.ToString();
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

[image]

As you can see - the event is triggered when user clicks on a button.. but how can I stop the it after the first output?

```
e.Handled = true;
```

does not help at all

Comment: What do you mean by "*the first output*"?

Comment: Do you want to remove the event or...?

Comment: Why don't you use a bool variable?

Comment: e.Handled = false - Or you can stop the event with e.Stop(); (I think)

Comment: there is no "e.cancel" method.. as well as "e.Stop()". **"What do you mean by "the first output"?"** you can see from the code that the textbox displays "pressed keys" so the complete answer to your question would be: "after the first keystroke output in the textbox"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get you right and you want to handle KeyPress event only once after clicking button, then you need unregister this handler in your `MyKeyPress`. Like this:

```
public void MyKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  textBox1.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(MyKeyPress);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just use PreviewKeyDown event instead of KeyDown. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarification on "*first output*" and the nature of your application you need to unhook the event handler, otherwise everytime you click the `Capture` button you will assign *another* delegate.

```
public void MyKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true; 
    string first = e.Modifiers.ToString(); 

    if (first != "None") 
    { 
        if ((e.KeyCode != Keys.ShiftKey) && (e.KeyCode != Keys.Alt) && (e.KeyCode != Keys.ControlKey)) 
        { 
            textBox1.Text = e.Modifiers.ToString() + " & " + e.KeyCode.ToString();
            textBox1.KeyDown -= MyKeyPress; 
        } 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        textBox1.Text = e.KeyCode.ToString();
        textBox1.KeyDown -= MyKeyPress;
    } 
    e.Handled = true; 
}
```

Comment: is there a difference between "textBox1.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(MyKeyPress);" (as suggested JleruOHeP) and "textBox1.KeyDown -= MyKeyPress;"? Anyway, +1 to rep for the answer.

Comment: @Alex - No `-= MyKeyPress` is shorthand for `-= new KeyEventHandler(MyKeyPress)`, they compile down to the same IL code.